# How to hide variable with Z3

Tags: z3, smt

Say I have

```
t1<x and x<t2
```

is it possible to hide variable x so that
`t1<t2` 
in Z3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use quantifier elimination for doing that. Here is an example:

```
(declare-const t1 Int)
(declare-const t2 Int)

(elim-quantifiers (exists ((x Int)) (and (< t1 x) (< x t2))))
```

You can try this example online at: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/kp0X

Comment: Thanks but why the result is t1-t2<=-2? and not t1-t2<0?

Comment: Because, `t1`, `t2` and `x` are integers. For integers we have that if `a < b` then `a <= b - 1`. Thus, combining the inequalities `t1 <= x - 1` and `x <= t2 - 1`, we get `t1 - t2 <= -2`. If we replace `Int` with `Real`, we will get a formula that is equivalent to `t1 - t2 < 0`.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated, as it yields "unsupported" as a result (also on rise4fun)

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution using Redlog of Reduce:

[image]